# Android animate off screen then animate back on

Tags: android, animation

I have code that makes an image animate left off the screen, then i want the image to animate right onto the screen later.  But when it is time to animate back on before it scrolls onto the screen it flickers in its final place then goes and animates onto the screen.

xml likes like this:

```
animate on
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-50%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="800" />
</set>

animate off

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p"
    android:duration="800" />
</set>




java code
        mEditMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (mEditMessage.getText().length()==0){
                Animation fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MessageActivity.this, R.anim.move_right_onto_screen);
                AnimationSet animateIn = new AnimationSet(false);
                animateIn.addAnimation(fade_in);

                animateIn.setFillAfter(true);
                mIvAttachment.startAnimation(animateIn);
                mIvAudio.startAnimation(animateIn);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
            if (mEditMessage.getText().length()==0){
                Animation fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MessageActivity.this, R.anim.move_left_off_screen);
                AnimationSet animate = new AnimationSet(false);

                animate.addAnimation(fade_out);

                animate.setFillAfter(true);
                mIvAttachment.startAnimation(animate);
                mIvAudio.startAnimation(animate);



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: User TranslateAnimation class for this . Its better as it will calculate the dimens at runtime . Its easy to understand and apply [Read this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html).

Comment: thanks i will take a look!

Comment: Its the part of ObjectAnimator So you can have a look on that that one first .

Comment: thanks that looked perfectly, do you know of any similar methods for animating making a view bigger?

Comment: Yeah There are classes for each type of animation at runtime like ScaleAnimation.You can also use Property Animation, Its easy to use and just few line of codes. I would prefer PropertyAnimation to animate a view .